# C# - Determine file path

Tags: c#, cursor, monogame

I am using the following code to load a custom cursor for my program:

```
public static Cursor LoadCustomCursor(string path)
{
    IntPtr hCurs = LoadCursorFromFile(path);
    if (hCurs == IntPtr.Zero) throw new Win32Exception(-2147467259, "Key game file missing. Please try re-installing the game to fix this error.");
    Cursor curs = new Cursor(hCurs);
    // Note: force the cursor to own the handle so it gets released properly.
    FieldInfo fi = typeof(Cursor).GetField("ownHandle", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    fi.SetValue(curs, true);
    return curs;
}
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern IntPtr LoadCursorFromFile(string path);
```

And then:

```
Cursor gameCursor = NativeMethods.LoadCustomCursor(@"C:/Users/User/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/myProj/myProj/Content/Graphics/Cursors/cursor_0.xnb");
Form gameForm = (Form)Control.FromHandle(Window.Handle);
```

I am wondering if this absolute path above will also work if the project folder is for example moved to D:/ partition or another folder on C:/? Can I do something like this:

```
string myStr = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
string output = myStr.Replace("bin\\Windows\\Debug\\myProj.exe", "Content\\Graphics\\Cursors\\cursor_0.xnb");
```

And use `output` for the path of the cursor file? Is `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` dynamic (changes every time the program folder is moved)? Or is it always the same as when the project was built?

Comment: Why dont you use a path relative to your executable?

Comment: Wait, I've never thought about that. It actually works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Environment.CurrentDirectory`. Example:

```
string cursorPath = @"Content\Graphics\Cursors\cursor_0.xnb";
string output = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, cursorPath);
```

Environment.CurrentDirectory returns the full path of the current working directory and you can use `@` to escape the literal `\` all at once if you place it in front of the string.

Comment: So this works no matter the location of the project's folder?

Comment: Yes, no matter where you put your project it will return the directory from where you application is executing. If you deploy your application to some other folder and run your application from that folder it will return that folder.

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed. Going to accept this answer in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

This approach is not the best way.

Better to use relative paths, not absolute.

You can use ".." to move one folder up from your current location.
For example

```
var output = @"..\..\..\Content\Graphics\Cursors\cursor_0.xnb";
```

Is equals to

```
string myStr = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
string output = myStr.Replace("bin\\Windows\\Debug\\myProj.exe", "Content\\Graphics\\Cursors\\cursor_0.xnb");
```

Comment: Actually I just found out that I can use a path, relative to my project dir.

Answer (score 0):

Your absolute path will only keep working if your cursor file lives at the exact path specified: `@"C:/Users/User/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/myProj/myProj/Content/Graphics/Cursors/cursor_0.xnb"`. Relating the cursor file's location to your .EXE file is a better idea, but you'll need to maintain the relative folder structure you specify in code. Your code now depends on the .EXE living in directory `<appRoot>\bin\Windows\Debug`, which you probably won't want when deploying your application. (Instead you'll probably put the .EXE in the application's root folder, with resource files going into subdirectories.) For such a structure, you could write (code was never compiled and may therefore contain typos or other errors):

```
var exe = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
var exeFolder = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(exe);
var cursorFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(exeFolder, "relative/path/to/your.cur";
```

(For added benefit, this code will keep working when the .EXE file is renamed.)
With this approach, you'll only need to ensure that the cursor file will be found in a particular location relative to your .EXE. Of course the same structure will need to exist both on your dev box and on target machines. Use MSBuild tasks in Visual Studio to copy your resource files to `$(OutDir)\relative\path\to`. For deployment to other machines, simply copy+paste the contents of your output folder, or create an installer that deploys files to the required folder structure.